# Old Session Isn't Flushed with Session::regenerate

Tags: php, laravel, session

I need some information about how Laravel cache session.

I am using file based Laravel session.

Scenario:

1. <strike>Run the web once to create the session in storage/framework/sessions.</strike>
2. <strike>Put some value in Session.</strike>
3. <strike>Delete that physical session file from storage/framework/sessions.</strike>
4. <strike>Refresh the site, and see a new physical file with exact session Id filename as before recreated, as well as all the data from previous session being restored to this new file.</strike>

<strike>My question is, where does Laravel store the session data? How to effectively erase the session data so that even a whole new physical session file recreated with the same filename wouldn't restore the old data.</strike>

The above issue has been resolved.

Another issue arise, running below code:

```
Session::forget('member');
Session::flush();
Session::regenerate();
```

The old session wasn't flush at all, all the data is still there. But the newly generated session start fresh.

How can I really flush the old session before moving to new session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the correct way to persist the new data in old session:

```
Session::forget('member');
Session::flush();
Session::save(); // trigger save to old session

Session::regenerate(true); // pass true to regenerate would delete the old session file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Under default settings your sessions are stored in a table called 'sessions' in your default database connection

destroy it